# is it possible to use a string variable on replaceAll?

Tags: java

I am trying to replace a line of string in a .txt file.
However, when i run my code, the program just deletes everything in the line including the spaces
Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String str;
        String temp = "";
        String oldtext = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
            oldtext += str + "\r\n";
            if (str.equals("I drink Java")) {
                temp = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(temp);
            }

        }
        br.close();
        String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(temp, "Hello");

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

file.txt

```
I drink Java
I sleep Java
This is test string 1
This is test string 20000
```

I am trying to replace "I sleep Java" line to "Hello" by using String variable temp. I am aware that it works by using `String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("I sleep Java","Hello");`
but i want to know if it's possible doing it the way I did. And if yes, can anyone tell me where I am wrong at?
Thanks! :)

Comment: replaceAll() is useful if you want to use a regexp. You don't. So just use replace().

Comment: did you get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at this:

> ```
> while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
>     oldtext += str + "\r\n";
>     if (str.equals("I drink Java")) {
>         temp = br.readLine();
>         System.out.println(temp);
>     }
> }
> ```

If the line is "I drink Java",
then you read the next line and store it into `temp`.
That line is never appended to `oldtext`,
like all the other lines.
So this line will be missing in `oldtext`.

Later,
when you perform this:

> ```
> String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(temp, "Hello");
> ```

Nothing matches `temp`, because `temp` is not part of `oldtext`.
Perhaps you want to append it, just like all other lines:

```
oldtext += temp + "\r\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up...u saved my assignment :D 
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `br.readLine()` to set `temp`:

```
while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
    oldtext += str + "\n";
    if (str.equals("I drink Java")) {
        temp = str+"\n";
    }
}
br.close();
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(temp, "Hello"+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are checking first the str contains `I drink Java` in below code. Just read the complete text in file first in to java variable and at last replace.

It will be more optimized , readable and clean

```
 while((str = br.readLine()) !=null) {
        oldtext += str + "\r\n";
        if(str.equals("I drink Java")){
        temp = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(temp); 
        }

}     br.close();
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(temp,"Hello");
```

**Something like below**

```
 while((str = br.readLine()) !=null) {
        oldtext += str + "\r\n";


}     br.close();
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("I drink Java","Hello");
```

**Best way will be**

```
String newText= "";
 while((str = br.readLine()) !=null) {

        if(str.equals("I drink Java")){
         str = "Hello";
        }
         newText+= str + "\r\n";

}     br.close();
```

Now simply write the new text

```
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        writer.write(newtext);
        writer.close();
```

Comment: notice the question asks about using a variable in `replaceAll()`.

Comment: @ItamarGreen  Sorry i did not get you here. `replaceAll()` will replace all occurrences of   `I drink Java`  in oldtext. So what's the issue  ?

Comment: he wanted to use a variable in `replaceAll()`.